# How to extract the first item in a list(even if the list is empty)

Tags: r

In R, I want to extract the first item from a nested list of lists; however sometimes the list might be empty.

e.g.:

```
myList <- list(
            list(ID = 1, Sales = 1000, Product = "Car"),
            list(ID = 2, Sales = 2000, Product = "Boat"),
            list(ID = 3, Sales = 1500, Product = "Bike")
)
myList2 <- list()
```

So when I make the following call:

```
myList[[1]]
myList2[[1]]
```

The first call returns a valid sub-list (`ID=1`, `Sales=1000`, `Product = "Car"`) but the second call returns an error -

> `Error in myList2[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`

Is there a simple call I can make that says "return item 1 when the list is populated, otherwise return `NULL` and do not throw an error"?

Comment: Do you want to extract 'ID' or just the `list` element

Comment: Your `mylist2` is an empty list.

Comment: The whole `list` element.  But I want to avoid the error message in example 2 when the list has 0 elements (in the project I am working on these lists are coming from a JSON object which sometimes return populated lists and sometimes empty lists - I am trying to ensure that the latter do not cause an error)

Comment: Yes `mylist2` is empty.  So I want to ensure that when I ask for the first `[[1]]` item in that list, I just get `NULL` returned

Comment: Consider using `pairlist()`, which will return `NULL` when empty; `pairlist()[[1]]` will return `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `first` function of `dplyr` package:

```
first(myList, default = NULL)
first(myList2, default = NULL)
```

More info on that function here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nth.html

Answer (score 4):

We can create a function to return `NULL` if the `length` is 0 or else to return the subset of the `list`

```
f1 <- function(lst, ind){
   if(length(lst) >=1) lst[[ind]] else NULL
}

f1(myList2, 1)
#NULL

f1(myList, 1)
#$ID
#[1] 1

#$Sales
#[1] 1000

#$Product
#[1] "Car"
```

Comment: That looks sensible; was hoping there was an already available function that could handle this without resorting to writing a bespoke one though! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tryCatch` in order to give it an alternative in case of an error, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(x){
    tryCatch(x, error = function(i)return(NULL))
}

f1(myList[[1]])
#$ID
#[1] 1

#$Sales
#[1] 1000

#$Product
#[1] "Car"

f1(myList2[[1]])
#NULL
```

Comment: That works as well, although I prefer akrun's answer as it specifically tests for the scenario in question rather than implicitly catching it when an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You get get the result using `[1]` and `el()` or `[[1]]`. `[1]` returns the list containing only the first element. It returns `NULL` on empty list. Then you have to extract the only element of this list using `el()` ir `[[1]]`.

See the example.

```
myList1 <- list(
  list(ID = 1, Sales = 1000, Product = "Car"),
  list(ID = 2, Sales = 2000, Product = "Boat"),
  list(ID = 3, Sales = 1500, Product = "Bike")
)

myList2 <- list()

el(myList1[1])
el(myList2[1])

myList1[1][[1]]
myList2[1][[1]]
```

Output:

```
> el(myList1[1])
$ID
[1] 1

$Sales
[1] 1000

$Product
[1] "Car"

> el(myList2[1])
NULL
```